# tkz-euclide package issue

Tags: tkz-euclide

This is my first question and this is the first time I am using LaTeX! I know most of the basic symbols and commands, `\usepackage{}` or `\frac{3}{4}` and I am using WinEdt as my text editor.

I am looking at a paper called tkz-euclide which contains information about how to draw geometrical figures using the tikz package(*in french*) and I want to be able to make figures like in the paper and I installed the tikz package. How do I do it? {[tkz-euclide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf)}

Here's the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\tkzSetUpLine[line width=2pt,color=orange!80!black]
\tkzSetUpCompass[line width=2pt,color=orange!80!black]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} \tkzDefPoint(2.25,0){A}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}{
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center O angle 30+60*\i](A) \tkzGetPoint{a\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {a\i} angle 120](O) \tkzGetPoint{b\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {a\i} angle 180](O) \tkzGetPoint{c\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {c\i} angle 120](a\i) \tkzGetPoint{d\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {c\i} angle 60](d\i) \tkzGetPoint{f\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {d\i} angle 60](b\i) \tkzGetPoint{e\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {f\i} angle 60](d\i) \tkzGetPoint{g\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {d\i} angle 60](e\i) \tkzGetPoint{h\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {e\i} angle 180](b\i) \tkzGetPoint{k\i}
\tkzDrawCircle(a\i,O) \tkzDrawCircle(b\i,a\i)
\tkzDrawCircle(c\i,a\i)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](f\i,d\i)(-120)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](e\i,d\i)(180)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](d\i,f\i)(180)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](g\i,f\i)(60)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](h\i,d\i)(60)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](k\i,e\i)(60) }
\tkzClipCircle(O,f0)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \tkzSetUpLine
                 [line width=2pt,color=orange!80!black]
? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

This is what it's supposed to look like:[image: Flower]

Comment: Welcome! You need to load the tikz-euclide package to access its commands.

Comment: How do you load the tikz-euclide package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works. You also need to say `\usetkzobj{all}`, which is hard to figure out if you do not speak French.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\tkzSetUpLine[line width=2pt,color=orange!80!black]
\tkzSetUpCompass[line width=2pt,color=orange!80!black]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} \tkzDefPoint(2.25,0){A}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}{
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center O angle 30+60*\i](A) \tkzGetPoint{a\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {a\i} angle 120](O) \tkzGetPoint{b\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {a\i} angle 180](O) \tkzGetPoint{c\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {c\i} angle 120](a\i) \tkzGetPoint{d\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {c\i} angle 60](d\i) \tkzGetPoint{f\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {d\i} angle 60](b\i) \tkzGetPoint{e\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {f\i} angle 60](d\i) \tkzGetPoint{g\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {d\i} angle 60](e\i) \tkzGetPoint{h\i}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center {e\i} angle 180](b\i) \tkzGetPoint{k\i}
\tkzDrawCircle(a\i,O) \tkzDrawCircle(b\i,a\i)
\tkzDrawCircle(c\i,a\i)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](f\i,d\i)(-120)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](e\i,d\i)(180)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](d\i,f\i)(180)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](g\i,f\i)(60)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](h\i,d\i)(60)
\tkzDrawArc[rotate](k\i,e\i)(60) }
\tkzClipCircle(O,f0)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]